# create a particular detail view

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

i need help to formulate a query.

my models are this:

```
class Rider(models.Model):
    id_rider = models.IntegerField(default = 0,blank= True, primary_key=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length = 256,blank= True)
```

[...]
        def **str**(self):
            return self.display_name

```
class Risultato(models.Model):
    TYPE_CHOICES = (('SR','sr'),('ITT', 'itt'),('HC', 'hc'),('1C','1c'),('TTT','ttt'))

    id_rider = models.ForeignKey(Rider,related_name='rider', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    id_stage = models.ForeignKey(Stage,related_name='team', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    type_ris = models.CharField(choices=TYPE_CHOICES,max_length = 256,blank= True)
    rank = models.IntegerField(default = 0,blank= True)
    punti = models.IntegerField(default = 0,blank= True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.id_raider,self.id_stage,self.rank
```

i need to create a Detail View to details of riders, somethings like this:

```
-------------------------------------------
```

Rider: [display_name]

age : [age]

...

...

--------SCORE HISTORY-----

stage   *sr/itt*       ttt        hc      1c      tot

1        100    null    10    0    110

2         null     20   5     10   35

Thanks in advance!!

**UPDATE**

i add the view and the template, but i can't see the table
view.py:

```
class RiderDetails(DetailView):

    model = Rider
    template_name = 'game/rider_detail.html'

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context_data = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context_data['risultato_qs'] = Risultato.objects.filter(id_rider=self.object)
        return context_data
```

rider_detail.html:

```
{% extends 'game/base.html'%}
{% block content %}
<h1>{{ rider.display_name }}</h1>
<table>
    <tbody>
    {% for risultato in risultato_qs %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ risultato.stage }}</td>
            <td>{{ risutato.type_ris }}</td>
            <td>{{ risutato.punti }}</td>
            ... etc ...
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>
{% endblock %}
```

[screen page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4NZfN.png)

Comment: What do those abbreviations stand for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick example might look like:

```
class RiderDetails(DetailView):

    model = Rider
    template_name = 'path_to_rider_template'

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context_data = super().get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        context_data['risultato_qs'] = Risultato.objects.filter(id_rider=self.object)
        return context_data
```

Then in your template you can, for example:

```
... Rider details here ...

<table>
    <tbody>
    {% for risultato in risultato_qs %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ risultato.stage }}</td>
            <td>{{ risutato.type_ris }}</td>
            ... etc ...
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: i tried it but i see only rider details, i don't see the table

Comment: Can you add your template and view to your question?